# Docusign Api Call Issue in React js

Tags: docusignapi, docusignconnect

After getting Access Token, I made API call on Postman ([https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{account_id}](https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/%7Baccount_id%7D) which was successfull. But when i tried to make simple axios/fetch request on React js by making a function. It is constantly showing me error:

AxiosError {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
code
:
"ERR_NETWORK"
config
:
{transitional: {…}, adapter: Array(2), transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), timeout: 0, …}
message
:
"Network Error"
name
:
"AxiosError"
request
:
XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
stack
:
"AxiosError: Network Error\n    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:41459:14)"
[[Prototype]]
:
Error
.

Can anyone tell that what is the issue in it?

I tried the code:

import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

const User = () => {
useEffect(() => {
const apiUrl = 'https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/{myaccount id here}';
const token = //mytoken;
const config = {
headers: {
'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`,
},
};

```
axios.get(apiUrl, config)
  .then(response => {
    // Handle the response data here
    console.log(response.data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // Handle the error here
    console.error(error);
  });
```

}, []);

return Check the browser console for the API response.;
};

export default User;

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to directly call the DocuSign API from a React application running in a browser?

If so, then the browser (not DocuSign and not React) will require you to use CORS. DocuSign supports CORS, start with the [blog post](https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/cors-here). And see the [MDN CORS docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) too.

Also, I suggest that you look into using the web standard [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to make your API calls rather than the axios library.